# Web app is in Users Facebook Apps section as approved but Facebook not returning verified==true

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, user-registration

I am using Facebook PHP SDK. There are some Facebook users that can't register or login with my site.

`$user_profile = $this->api('/me');`

Everything is working for most Facebook users joining the site. But I have just created two new Facebook accounts to test this due to a user complaint and both new facebook accounts are not returning the `$user_profile['verified']` data.

I get:

```
array (size=11)
'id' => string '10000501019xxxx' (length=15)
'name' => string 'Toby xxxx' (length=12)
'first_name' => string 'Toby' (length=4)
'last_name' => string 'xxxx' (length=7)
'link' => string 'http://www.facebook.com/toby.xxxx.90' (length=39)
'username' => string 'toby.xxxx.90' (length=15)
'gender' => string 'male' (length=4)
'email' => string 'xxxx99@gmail.com' (length=22)
'timezone' => int -6
'locale' => string 'en_US' (length=5)
'updated_time' => string '2013-01-08T00:38:06+0000' (length
```

The web application is in the facebook users Account Settings > Apps and shows as approved.

Even though everything is working up to the point where the application is registered in the Facebook user's apps, Facebook still is not returning the `$user_profile['verified'] == true` therefore the user can't finish the registration.

I tried a work around where the after the user checks their Facebook profile to see if the App is there and approved they can still register. But, when trying to return and login, the `$user_profile = $this->api('/me');` still doesn't contain the `$user_profile['verified'] == true`.

I really don't know how many users are running into this. But like I said two new test Facebook accounts that have the web app approved still don't register as having verified the app.

I don't know what else to do since I am receiving registrations and logins.  The users that can't have the web App in their Facebook Aps section. Just seems like Facebook is not returning the `verified=true` for some reason.

Any ideas?

I took out the test of if the user had verified the account and, of course, the user can register and login. I deleted the app from the user's Facebook account then went back to the app to login. Facebook dialog then requires the user to re-approve the app.  Strange that some users' data will not return that they have verified the app.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but are the users actually verified? For a start, the email addresses need to be confirmed. The user being verified or not has nothing to do with whether they can use your app or not

Comment: You are correct. I misunderstood the meaning of verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Strange that some users' data will not return that they have verified the app.

I think you might have misunderstood the meaning of the `verified` field here.

This has **nothing** to do with the user authorizing your specific app!

Instead it means whether the user has verified their account with Facebook, i.e. confirmed their identity by mobile phone, credit card or some other means.

Comment: You are correct. Totally misunderstood the meaning. Thank you.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Verified Users


A user is considered verified if she takes any of the following actions:

    Registers for mobile
    Confirms her account via SMS
    Enters a valid credit card